# Setting action bar elevation programmatically throws NullPointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-elevation

After setting the elevation of the action bar programmatically, the code becomes highlighted in yellow and the warning below gets thrown. What can be done to remove this warning?

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

**Warning**

> Method invocation 'getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a null check:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try:


ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar != null) {
   actionBar.setElevation(0);
}
```